# How to accomplish a rich snippet with Twitter?

Tags: seo, google, social-media, search-results

I would like to enhance my CTR for my pages and/or posts. When I publish these I tend to Tweet them so they become known. When doing some research on 'Grails' I just noticed the following snippet in Google:

[image: Twitter Google rich snippet]

Unfortunately my Google snippets never include the Tweet. My question is, how do I make sure that my tweet is included in the 'rich' snippet as shown above? In other words, which steps do I need to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is one of Google's social search results. Because someone in your social graph (Hans Westerbeek) has shared this item, you'll see it higher in **your** results and have it noted with the rich presentation.

This type of personalization should provide results that are more trustworthy to end users.

Your posts will have this presentation when it is shared by someone in the user's social graph. The ways to increase the odds of this presentation have everything to do with your social reach and how often your content is shared within your community.

Comment: Thanks. I just opened an incognito window in Google Chrome and submitted the same search query. This time the 'Twitter part' wasn't visible...